# Maven error in Anypoint studio: Unresolveable build extension

Tags: java, maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to build a new project using maven in anypoint studio. However, I get the following error:

```
[16:42:59] Running: mvn clean package mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.1/mule-app-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.1/mule-app-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/tools/maven/mule-app-maven-plugin/1.1/mule-app-maven-plugin-1.1.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.1 @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
@ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany:soap_wsclient_maven:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\Mahsa\Desktop\AnypointStudio\Workspace\soap_wsclient_maven\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:pom:1.1 from/to mule-public (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public): Connect to repository.mulesoft.org:443 [repository.mulesoft.org/52.7.200.18] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: mule @ line 8, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginManagerException
```

In the preferences I have set the "Installed JREs" to point to a JDK installation (JDK1.8.0_131). The maven version I am using is 3.5.0.

The POM is configured as follows (including only the related part in the error):

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>soap_wsclient_maven</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule soap_wsclient_maven Application</name>
....
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

P.S. I know this question has been asked several times. But I couldn't resolve my issue reviewing the similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a proxy issue. So I resolved the issue by adding the proxy configurations on the setting.xml in maven:

```
 <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>proxypass</password>
  <host>proxy.host.net</host>
  <port>80</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```